# CVCalendar DayView.date Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, github, calendar

I'm using the CVCalendar by Mozharovsky from GitHub.
I'm trying to mark specific days using this method:

```
func supplementaryView(shouldDisplayOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> Bool
{
    if(dayView.date.day == day && dayView.date.month == month) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

The problem is that the dayView.date is nil sometimes which causes an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How can I avoid the nils and the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the basic Optional Unwrapping to test if it's defined and do what suits your needs :

```
func supplementaryView(shouldDisplayOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> Bool
{
    if let date = dayView.date {
        if(date.day == day && date.month == month) {
            return true
        }
    } else {
        // date is nil :(
    }

    return false
}
```